# Add more types in Ion Response

Tags: android, json, types, android-ion, ion-koush

Using `Ion` by Koush, I need to make a `JSON` request that I cast directly into `type`, this way:

```
public interface UserCallback extends FutureCallback<Response<User>> {}

Builders.Any.B builder;

TypeToken<User> userType = new TypeToken<User>() {}

void userRequest(Context ctx, UserCallback callback) {
    builder = Ion.with(context).load("GET", "https://myendpoi.nt/");
    builder.as(userType).withResponse().setCallback(callback);
}

userRequest(getApplicationContext(),
    new UserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception ex, Response<User> result) {

            // Cast my spell with User object...

        }
    });
```

The problems is: sometime the server responds with a `JSON` that cannot be reflected in the `User` class, but need to go in another object (such as `Pet.class`).

Well, I know I can get the response as a generic `JsonObject` and cast it subsequently, but my question is: there is a more elegant way to do this? It's possible add 2 `Response` in `FutureCallback`? so I can do such a thing:

```
public interface UserCallback extends FutureCallback<Response<User>, Response<Pet>> {}
```

or something else?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

extend `User` class in `Pet` class or the other way and use the base class in `FutureCallback`. Then cast to whatever class need later in response.

Comment: But this way I have the `Pet` class with methods and properties fo the `User` class (or vice-versa), it's not what I want.